# refrofit2 request with filter param. @Query instead of @Path

Tags: retrofit2

I have following request which I need to set using Retrofit 2 library.
I have found a lot of variants, but had no luck with it.

So my URL is:

http://server/api/v1/items?filter=param1==111;param2==222;param3==333;&select=param1;param2;param3

I tried to write in following format:

```
@GET("api/v1/items?filter=param1=={param1};param2=={param2};param3=={param3}")
Call<ItemResponse> getItems(@Path("param1") String param1, @Path("param2") String param2, @Path("param3") String param3);
```

but in this case I have an Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "filter=param1=={param1};param2=={param2};param3=={param3}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
    for method IAramexApi.getItems
```

So, I need to use @Query annotation, but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Every example I saw covered following query:

> method?param1==value1...

For my case I need something like

> method?filter=param1==value1...

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
 @GET("api/v1/items")
    Call<ItemResponse> getItems(@Query("param1") String param1, @Query("param2") String param2, @Query("param3") String param3);
```